# Internal Server Error while setting up 2Fa in phpmyadmin 4.8 dev

Tags: server, phpmyadmin, internal

So. Few hours ago I read that new development version of phpmyadmin supports 2FA. It excited me a lot, couse I felt lack of security in my previous installation of phpmyadmin. I successfully installed dev version 4.8, but on the moment of activation 2FA i got 500 Internal Server Error. It appears after clicking "Configure two-factor authentication". Screenshot is attached.

English versoin of error:
"Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status."

Is it a bug, or just my mistake somewhere?

I installed all the necessary extensions that were asked by phpmyadmin.

P.S. Sorry for my english and for being noob. lol

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPrd3.png)

Comment: Please put the error in the question and not an image. You'll also want to translate to english.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the problem is that php-gd is not on the target system...